# Proof of asymptotic stability of quadrotor attitude error with nonlinear controller

Tags: rotations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I'm looking at the paper "Multicopter attitude control for recovery from large disturbances" ([pdf here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09143.pdf)).

There's a short proof of the asymptotic stability of the following skew-symmetric controller using Barbalat's lemma, on page 3: $$\alpha_e = -K_\omega \omega_e - \frac{1}{2}K_Rv(R_e - R_e^T) \\
= -K_\omega \omega_e - K_R\sin\rho_e\mathbf{n_e}$$

$R_d$ is the desired attitude and $R$ is the current attitude. $R_e$ is the error between these relative to the body frame, $R_e := R_d^TR_e$

$\mathbf{n_e}$ and $\rho_e$ are the axis and angle of rotation of $R_e$, so that $\omega_e = \dot{\rho_e}\mathbf{n_e}$, $\alpha = \ddot{\rho_e}\mathbf{n_e}$ and $\dot{R_e} = R_e[\omega_e]_\times$

$v$ is the inverse cross product matrix operator, so that $\mathbf{x} = v([\mathbf{x}]_\times)$.

I'm on board with the proof up to and including the conclusion that $\omega_e \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. My trouble is that I can't find a proof for the assertion that this also implies that $R_e \rightarrow I$.

One possible answer is to show that $\omega_e \rightarrow 0$ implies $\alpha_e \rightarrow 0$, but I don't think we can just swap the derivative and limit of $\omega_e$ in this case. Another thing I tried is substituting $\omega_e = -K_\omega^{-1} \alpha_e - \frac{1}{2}K_\omega^{-1}K_Rv(R_e - R_e^T)$ into the Lyapunov function derivative $\frac{dJ}{dt}$ in the hopes that I would get something of the form $\alpha_e^TM\alpha_e + n_e^TNn_e$ from which the result should follow assuming positive definiteness of the matrix products, but there are multiple terms of the form $\alpha_e^TKn_e$ which get in the way of this approach. Any ideas on proceeding?

Comment: Could you add the definition of $R_e$?

Comment: @SampleTime Sure, I've added $R_e$ and a few of the other definitions

Comment: I am not sure how to treat $\dot{R}$ (resp. the $\dot{R}_e$)... Its a function of $\rho_e$ (eq. 17), so as far as I can tell your system has $4$ states in total (three $\omega$ and $\rho$), right? Doesn't that give multiple ODEs for the same $\rho_e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to conclude that for certain initial conditions it holds that $R_e\to I$ one can use the fact that $d/dt\,J^{SS}\leq0$ and by substituting the asymptotic result of $\omega_e\to0$ into the dynamics of $\omega_e$ itself, using the proposed control law (assuming that $\alpha_{e,des}^{SS}$ is the same as $\alpha_e$)

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \omega_e = -K_\omega\,\omega_e - K_R\,\sin\rho_e\,\mathbf{n}_e. \tag{1}
$$

Namely in the limit of $t\to\infty$ the Lyapunov function, together with its two derivatives and Barbalat’s lemma, shows that $\omega_e\to0$ and $d/dt\,\omega_e\to0$. Substituting this into $(1)$ yields that as $t\to\infty$

$$
0 = 0 - K_R\,\sin\rho_e\,\mathbf{n}_e, \tag{2}
$$

which can only be true if $\sin\rho_e\to0$. When only considering $-\pi<\rho_e\leq\pi$ implies that either $\rho_e\to0$ or $\rho_e\to\pi$.

The author does skips a bit by saying that if $\rho_e\neq\pi$ then $\rho_e\to0$ and thus $R_e\to I$. Namely it can be shown that $\rho_e=\pi$ is a saddle point so, similar to an inverted pendulum, there are initial conditions (also with $\rho_e\neq\pi$) that still do converge to $\rho_e=\pi$. But from the authors argument it can de deduced that $\rho_e=0$ and $\omega_e=0$ is a locally asymptotically stable equilibrium point.

Comment: It is not uncommon that published papers are worded in very compact and abstract ways, since often papers in journals are limited in how many words they are allowed to have. So prepare yourself to decipher more papers in the future.

Comment: I guess the assertion that $\frac{d}{dt} \omega_e \rightarrow 0$ is the part that I'm missing here

Comment: I guess if we know that $\frac{d}{dt} \omega_e$ is uniformly continuous then it follows from BL, but I don't see how this can be assumed.

Comment: Ah ok, we can show that $ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \omega_e $ is bounded, so $\frac{d}{dt} \omega_e$ is unformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that $\alpha_e$ is uniformly continuous:

$$\dot{\alpha_e} = -K_{\omega}\alpha_e - K_R \cos(\rho_e) \dot{\rho_e} \mathbf{n_e}
                 = -K_{\omega}(-K_{\omega}\omega_e - K_R \sin(\rho_e)\mathbf{n_e}) - K_R \cos(\rho_e) \omega_e$$

$$\dot{\alpha_e} = K_{\omega}^2 \omega_e + K_{\omega} K_R \sin(\rho_e)\mathbf{n_e} - K_R \cos(\rho_e) \omega_e $$

$\omega_e$, $\sin(\rho_e)$ and $\cos(\rho_e)$ are all bounded, so $\dot{\alpha_e}$ is bounded and therefore $\alpha_e$ is uniformly continuous.

$\omega(t)$ has the finite limit $\omega(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and so by Barbalat's lemma, $\alpha(t) \rightarrow 0$
.